# Could not load file or assembly in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle

I am using an assembly that connects to sql server and oracle.
I can choose weather my application should connect to sql server or oracle.
By the way, this assembly's throws an error in finally statement.

```
        try
        {
            switch (this.DataBaseType)
            {
                case DataBaseType.SqlServer:
                    _sqlLib.CommitTransaction();
                    break;
                case DataBaseType.Oracle:
                    _oraLib.CommitTransaction();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            switch (this.DataBaseType)
            {
                case DataBaseType.SqlServer:
                    _sqlLib.Close();
                    break;
                case DataBaseType.Oracle:
                    _oraLib.Close();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

_oraLib is another class that is using Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

In this application, I am not using oracle but using sql server.

So, I didn't copy that Oracle.DataAccess.dll into my project.

In try statement, it passes okay.

But in finally statement, even though this.DataBaseType returnsd SqlServer, it throws an error "Could not load file or assembly~~~~ 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342'.

If I block out
    // _oraLib.Close();

It's fine. It works fine.

What is the matter with this?

I thought the instance of class should not be loaded until I decide to use it.

Why my application is throwing this error even though this DataBaseType indicates SqlServer.

Answer (score 2):

Some time it happens because the oracle dll is 32 bit and your application is build on 64 bit
changing the app to 32 bit may solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try and report the result. By the way, do you know the reason why?

Comment: if the reason is 32/64 mixup i causes a [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you reference a dll in code it will be loaded, and it doesn't matter if the code is hit or not.

If you don't want to include the oracle dll in a release when you know it will not be used, you have to hide it behind an abstraction, and load the required assembly by hand at runtime.

You could do this with Dependency Injection, and a decent container like [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx)

edit:
To clarify, you can add a reference to a dll in project reference and it will not be loaded until it is used some place in the code. And as James states this happens when the JIT compiling occurs, so the actual code line that invokes the dll need not be run.

Comment: By the way, the assembly's name that handles database(which has reference to Oracle.DataAccess.dll) is "DbConn". My application called WebApp1 is referencing this DbConn.dll. And "WebApp1" is not referencing Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

Comment: re: Assembly loading - what you said is not strictly true. Unless it is loaded explicitly, a referenced assembly will not be loaded until code that uses one of it's types is JIT compiled. The DI approach is a good one though. The OP's code references such a type, so it will try to load the Oracle assembly.